# Renaming multiple files in a folder using python with list of new names from text file

Tags: python

how can i rename multiple files in a folder which are in order by numbers and i have a text file with the names that i want to rename with also in order.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\abc')
with open('new_names') as f:
    new_list = f.read()
    for file in os.listdir():
    src = file
    dst = new_list
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

> error dest should be string

Comment: mind you i'm replacing the old names with new

Answer (score 0):

In your code , you are passing file type as destination  whereas you need to provide string type for your new destination .

Please find the below code snippet for your reference .

```
import os
with open('new_names') as f:           
    new_list = f.read().split()  // read file and split dest names
    i=0                          // for assigning specific dest name in os.rename command
    for file in os.listdir('/temp/'):
        src = file
        dst = new_list[i]
        os.rename('/temp/'+src, '/temp/'+dst)
        i+=1
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, had to add os.chdir() also still geeting some errors due to the name syntax from new names but overall old names are replaced with new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate on both the content of the folder and the list of new file names using zip:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\abc')
with open('new_names', 'r') as f:
    for src, dst in zip(os.listdir(), f):
        os.rename(src, dst)
```